# Chrome Mac and Chrome Window has different font spacing

Tags: css, windows, macos, google-chrome, fonts

Hi I have this problem on font spacing for different OS on Chrome.

This is the screenshot from MAC Chrome,
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0382ihbwa3

This is the screenshot from Windows Chrome,
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0752ihdi26

Is there anyway to make them look the same?, 
I don't have any problem with slight differences on content spacing on MAC vs Windows but this one affects the Main nav sections alignment.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the font anti-aliasing ("font smoothing") that each operating system employs. Users can change the default settings of how much font anti-aliasing to apply (and at which minimum font-size to not apply font anti-aliasing, for legibility) however web developers do not get a say in the matter. I believe the only true way to have it display with the same anti-aliasing on any computer is to put text in an image, which is definitely not recommended -_- sorry ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome will soon be transitioning to use DirectWrite for font rendering, instead of GDI. This means it'll be able to use proper subpixel rendering of webfonts, like other Windows applications (inc Firefox and IE). It's a known bug that has been around for a long time: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124406.

You can enable DirectWrite rendering now on Chrome Beta/Canary, but it's at the price of security because sandboxing is disabled. It's nice to know it's coming though: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692#c109